# Can't see tinymce features

Tags: html, django, tinymce

I am partly new to django and completely new to tinymce. I add these lines to my form and I don't see the tinymce features in textarea.

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `<textarea>` on your page so TinyMCE has nothing to initialize itself on.  The following documentation page outlines what you need to do to get TinyMCE working on a web page:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/basic-setup/

From that page:

> Selector configuration is required for TinyMCE integration. Selector
> configuration uses CSS selector syntax to determine which elements on
> the page are editable through TinyMCE.
>
> TinyMCE visually replaces the selected element with an iframe (the
> editable content area) and the UI elements (such as toolbar, menu bar,
> and status bar).
>
> The following example replaces all textarea elements on the page with
> TinyMCE instances:
>
> `tinymce.init({   selector: 'textarea' });`
>
> TinyMCE can also match an id attribute.  The following example
> replaces a textarea element with the id "default" on the page:
>
> `tinymce.init({   selector: 'textarea#default' });`

Comment: So how can I make it happen?